# AngularJS + PassPort with autofill and remember password

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, passwords, autofill

I've got a login page on my web app with 2 input (email / password). Actually everything works well with NodeJS / PassPort / Angular. However I've got a problem with autofill and remembering password on Chrome and Firefox.

1) On Chrome, browser doesn't ask me if I want to save password or not, there is no auto-fill, it doesn't remember anything on my form. This is pretty annoying.

2) On Firefox, browser ask me to save the password and saves it. However, when i'm back on it, my input are filled but if I click "login", nothing happens, I've to edit value in each field before login.

I've read a lot of thing about AJAX and Auto-Fill, however i'm totally new with that kind of stuff and I don't understand everything.

Here is my front-end code:

login.html

```
<form class="form-signin"
                      name="form"
                      ng-submit="login(form)"
                      novalidate>

                    <div ng-class="{'has-error': form.email.$error.mongoose}">
                        <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Email"
                               name="email"
                               ng-model="user.email"
                               required
                               autofocus
                               mongoose-error>
                        <p class="help-block"
                           ng-show="form.email.$error.mongoose">
                            {{ errors.email }}
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div ng-class="{'has-error': form.password.$error.mongoose}">
                        <input type="password"
                               class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Password"
                               name="password"
                               ng-model="user.password"
                               required
                               mongoose-error>
                        <p class="help-block"
                           ng-show="form.password.$error.mongoose">
                            {{ errors.password }}
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group has-error">
                        <p class="help-block">{{ error.other }}</p>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block" type="submit"> Sign in </button>

                    <span class="clearfix"></span>
                </form>
```

login.js (controller)

```
$scope.login = function(form) {
      var str = $scope.user.email;
      Auth.login('password', {
          'email': str.toLowerCase(),
          'password': $scope.user.password
        },
        function(err) {
          $scope.errors = {};

          if (!err) {
            $location.path('/page/1');
          } else {
            angular.forEach(err.errors, function(error, field) {
              form[field].$setValidity('mongoose', false);
              $scope.errors[field] = error.type;
            });
            $scope.error.other = err.message;
          }
      });
```

thanks for helping.

Comment: Please share it in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

1. Check this discussion https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth/issues/58 . Kind of a chrome bug.
2. Try https://github.com/tbosch/autofill-event. Works fine with my project.